# Ajax autosave multiple fields

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autosave

I have a page that has fields editable via contenteditable.  I am autosaving the fields via ajax after the user edits the field.  The problem is, I have multiple fields on the same page and when I try to autosave more than one field, either one field won't work or gets overwritten with the same content as the other field.

This is the code that I am using to update the database and it works exactly how I want it to for the "name" field.

```
$('.editname').keyup(function() {
delay(function(){
    var name= $('.editname').text();
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"update.php",
        data:"name="+name,
        success:function(data){
            console.log('success!');
        }
    });
}, 500 );
});

var delay = (function(){
var timer = 0;
return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
};
})();
```

However if I try to edit it like the following or duplicate it and give it a different name, it will not work properly to update another field along with the first field.

```
$('.editname').keyup(function() {
delay(function(){
    var name= $('.editname').text();
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"update.php",
        data:"name="+name,
        success:function(data){
            console.log('success!');
        }
    });
}, 500 );
});

$('.editsummary').keyup(function() {
delay(function(){
    var summary= $('.editsummary').text();
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"update.php",
        data:"summary="+summary,
        success:function(data){
            console.log('success!');
        }
    });
}, 500 );
});

var delay = (function(){
var timer = 0;
return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
};
})();
```

What am I doing wrong in the above block of code?

Comment: how are you naming your fields? i mean all fields have attribute name="name" or some thing like this name="name[]"?

Comment: <h1 class="name">
     <div class="editname" id="name" contenteditable placeholder="Your Name"><?php echo $row_update['name']; ?></div>
    </h1>

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a usual error developers get into when they copy and paste code.

```
var name= $('.editsummary').text();
```

This should read:

```
var summary = $('.editsummary').text();
```

---

**EDIT**

This is how you do it properly. Have one generic auto-save handler and re-use it.

For example (html/js):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// When Page Loads
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Handle Auto Save
    $('.autosaveEdit').keyup(function() {
        var fieldName = $(this).attr('name');
        var fieldValue = $(this).val();
        delay(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "update.php",
                data: { fName: fieldName, fValue: fieldValue },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('success!');
                }
            });
        }, 500 );
    });

});

var delay = (function() {
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms) {
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();

</script>

Firstname: <input type="text" class="autosaveEdit" name="firstname" />
<br />
Lastname: <input type="text" class="autosaveEdit" name="lastname" />
```

Now, on your **update.php**

```
<?php

// Get the post data
$fieldName = isset($_POST['fName']) ? $_POST['fName'] : '';
$fieldValue = isset($_POST['fValue']) ? $_POST['fValue'] : '';

// Now save the $fieldValue against $fieldName in your db (if neither is empty)
```

So, in my example form, if I start editing the "firstname" input field, the auto-save will post the following to update.php:

`print_r($_POST)`

```
Array
(
    [fName] => firstname
    [fValue] => hello
)
```

Comment: Oops!  Of course I pasted the wrong code in when I asked the question, however with the code fixed the way you suggested, it is updating the "summary" field correctly and erasing whatever data is in the "name" field.

Comment: see my updated response. I imagine you'll have to update your code a bit. Try my example, once you figure out how it's working, it will be easy to update your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've tweaked your example a little to get it to work with JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eHz4t/

```
<div class="editname" contenteditable="true">my name</div>
<div class="editsummary"contenteditable>my summary</div>
```

It works properly. You can open the network console and see the traffic being sent.